# CSS compatibility with different browsers

Tags: asp.net, css, styles, element

I have an Asp.Net create user wizard and trying to modify and arrange its labels to look same in every browser.

Now the problem is it looks fine in chrome but it looks same in IE9 and Firefox.

This is how it looks in chrome:

[image]

When I get into inspect here it shows the element .style property on the right which has two elements ie `position:absolute` and Z-index:2 which makes everything scrap.

[image]

Here come the problem with IE and firefox:

[image]

When it comes to firefox and IE it neglects everything:
[image]

I have give the below properties in my css file as shown below but this works only for chrome so I would like to know how would I change it for IE and as well as Firefox

```
.signtbl
{
z-index:2;
position:relative !important;
}
```

This is my entire code for my control:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
  DisableCreatedUser="True" MailDefinition-BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/NewAccountTemplate.htm" MailDefinition-From="noreply@imgaid.com" LoginCreatedUser="False" MailDefinition-IsBodyHtml="True" MailDefinition-Priority="High" MailDefinition-Subject="Pending Activation">
  <ContinueButtonStyle BorderStyle="None" CssClass="btn big" Font-Size="12px"/>
  <CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="btn big" Height="30px" 
            Width="125px" BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="12px" />
      <MailDefinition BodyFileName="~/EmailTemplates/NewAccountTemplate.htm" 
          From="noreply@xyz.com" IsBodyHtml="True" Priority="High" 
          Subject="Pending Activation">
      </MailDefinition>
      <WizardSteps>
          <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="right">
                              <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="signtbl">User Name:</asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                  ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                  CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                 <div id="divUsernameAvailability" runat="server"></div>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="right">
                              <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="signtbl">Password:</asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                  ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                  CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="right">
                              <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                  AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="signtbl">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                  ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                  ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." 
                                  ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="right">
                              <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="signtbl">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                  ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                  CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                  <div id="divEmailAvailability" runat="server"></div>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <%--<tr>
                          <td align="right">
                              <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question" CssClass="signtbl">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
                                  ToolTip="Security question is required." 
                                  ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="right">
                              <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer" CssClass="signtbl">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#0099CC" BackColor="#FAFFBD"></asp:TextBox>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
                                  ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" 
                                  CssClass="signupvalidators" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          </td>
                      </tr>--%>
                  <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="UsernameLength" runat="server" 
                          ErrorMessage="Username should be minimum 5-10 characters." 
                          ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" 
                          ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{5,10}$" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="center" colspan="2">
                              <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                  ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                  Display="Dynamic" 
                                  ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
                                  ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                              <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <td  align="center" colspan="2">
                       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="PasswordLength" runat="server"  Display="Dynamic"
                                  ErrorMessage="Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1" 
                                  ControlToValidate="Password" ValidationExpression="(?=^.{7,51}$)([A-Za-z]{1})([A-Za-z0-9!@#$%_\^\&amp;\*\-\.\?]{5,49})$" 
                              ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                       <td  align="center" colspan="2">
                          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                                ControlToValidate="Email"  ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid e-mail address." ValidationExpression="^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$"  ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                      </td> 
                      </tr>
                  </table>

                  <%-- <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressUserDetails" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <div style="position: absolute; top: 215px; left:140px;">
                                    <img src="img/Loader.gif" alt="loading" /><br />
                                </div>
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>--%>
              </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
          <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                          <td align="center" colspan="2">
                              Complete</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                              Your account has been successfully created.</td>
                      </tr>
                      <%--<tr>
                          <td align="right" colspan="2">
                              <asp:Button ID="ContinueButton" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
                                  CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Continue" CssClass="btn big" 
                                  Font-Size="12px" Text="Continue" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>--%>
                  </table>
              </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
      </WizardSteps>
  </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: What's your reason for using `position:absolute`? there should be no need. If you take this out the inputs should then line up with the labels in all browsers.

Comment: Position absolute is indeed causing the collapse of the two elements(Indeed, WHY?). The DOM won't consider the width of both items because they are position absolutely. Therefore, the tabular structure you use collapses to this.

Comment: @Deadlykipper-I didn't use any position:absolute the element.style property itself is showing as absolute and yes tha's what I have done in my stylesheet as mentioning it as position:relative !important.But this is neglecting with firefox and IE

Answer (score -2):

why dont you try using tables to align your controls in grid structure that might often help.
here's what you can do.Create a div where you want to place your controls
within the div first create a tabular structure then place control in individual  
 try may be this could help

Comment: As I can see on screens above - He's using tables, what is wrong.

Comment: @User1155418-The reason for my tables is actually I need to expand my control to be more specific to work with it.

Comment: @DotNetter - paste your code to jsfiddle.net - it'd be easier to help

Comment: It is a dot net control and I can't post it,otherwise I would have done it.

Comment: @DotNetter-Please put up your style sheet too along with the page for better reference screen shots are just not clear

Comment: @user1155418-I have added my entire code and there is nothing specific with my css.